# Somar valor total final usando group by MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a tabela Vendas e a tabela vendedor e gostaria de saber o % de vendas de cada vendedor.

> table vendedor

```
Id  | Vendedor |
1   | Fulano   |
2   | Beltrano |
```

> table pedido

```
Id    |  Id_Vendedor  | Valor    | Desconto  | Deflacionado
1     |  1            | 17800.00 | 800.00    | 452.00
2     |  1            | 11400.25 | 351.00    | 127.00
3     |  2            | 341.00   | 10.00     | 0.00
```

**Minha consulta está da seguinte forma**

```
SELECT SUM(Valor - Desconto - Deflacionado) as tt
INNER JOIN pedido ON vendedor.Id = pedido.Id_Vendedor
GROUP BY pedido.Id_vendedor
```

Estou usando está consulta de php, no while eu obtenho os valores agrupados por vendedor e para fazer o porcentual preciso acumular o valor acumulado de cada vendedor em uma variavel dentro do loop, porém queria que fosse na própria consulta para mostrar o % já na frente do valor acumulado, conforme ilustração na tabela a seguir.

```
Valor     |     Vendedor      |     %
27470.25  |     Fulano        |     98.81 %
331.00    |     Beltrano      |     1.19 %
```

```html
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Nome</th>
<th>Valor</th>
<th>%</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Fulano</td>
<td>R$ 27.470,25</td>
<td>98.81 %</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Beltrano</td>
<td>R$ 331,00</td>
<td>1.19 %</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<th>Total</th>
<th>27.801,25</th>
<th>100 %</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Para somar tudo não seria assim:
`(SUM(Valor) - SUM(Desconto) - SUM(Deflacionado)) AS tt`?

Comment: Entao como eu uso um group by, ele faz dessa forma a soma, porem para cada vendedor, e não o montate, quero saber se consigo fazer a soma total nesta query sem ter q criar subquerys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para reaproveitar uma *query* pode usar uma `@variavel` do lado do MySQL, em vez do PHP:

Fiz um exemplo com valores simples, para você entender o uso isolado da variável. depois tem que adaptar para o seu agrupamento.

```
  SET @total := 0;

  SELECT item, valor, @total := @total + valor AS subtotal
  FROM   docs
  ORDER BY coluna_que_garante_ordenacao_correta

UNION

  SELECT 'TOTAL', @total, '';
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b77d27/1)**.

Uma alternativa é usar o `UNION` com `SUM`, mas aí acaba processando duas vezes o DB:

```
  SELECT item, valor, @total := @total + valor AS subtotal
  FROM   tabela
  ORDER BY coluna_que_garante_ordenacao_correta

UNION

  SELECT 'TOTAL', SUM( valor ) AS total, ''
  FROM   tabela
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b4edf/1)**.

Na prática, acho muito melhor deixar a variável no PHP mesmo, pois você pode controlar melhor a formatação separada no HTML, e em termos de velocidade e memória é irrisória a diferença. Além disso, evita transportar uma coluna a mais na comunicação entre o My e o PHP.